# Adding mandatory [data-testid] prop for MUI components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

is it possible to extend the ButtonProps, for example, to make the [data-testid] prop mandatory?

Something like:

```
declare module '@mui/material/Button' {
  export interface Button extends ButtonProps {
    ['data-testid']: string;
  }
}
```

but that actually works.

Comment: Of course, it's possible and there are several ways for this. but I don't know what you want. Please clear your question.

Comment: Hi, so when using an MUI button this: 

<Button>Hello</Button>

would throw a missing required prop error, and this: 

<Button {...{['data-testid']: 'test'}}>Hello</Button>
wouldn't.

Comment: If so, why don't you make custom button? it's easy way for this.